# Mongoose aggregate column as average and output with additional fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to query the database get a grouped result which will calculate an average result and in addition, output additional fields from the object.

I have a schema which like this:

```
    resturantName: {type:String},
    resturantLocation: {type:String},    
    comfort: {type: Number, min: min, max: max, default: 0},
    cleanliness: {type: Number, min: min, max: max, default: 0},
    valueForMoney: {type: Number, min: min, max: max, default: 0},
    avgRating: {type: Number}
```

I query the database according to **'resturantLocation'** and would like to calculate the **'total_average_rating'**, in addition output the restaurant name & location.

I've tried multiple queries but I keep getting various errors, here is my latest attempt:

```
query = [
    { "$match": { "resturantName": resturantName} },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 1,
            "resturantName": resturantName,
            "resturantLocation": "resturantLocation",
            "total_average_rating": { "$avg": "$avgRating" }
        }
    }   
];
```

I looked into using **$project**, but I doubt it fits my needs.

Please advise.

Comment: You can try `query = [{ "$match": { "resturantName": resturantName} },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$resturantName",
            "resturantLocation": {"$first":"$resturantLocation"},
            "total_average_rating": { "$avg": "$avgRating" }
        }
    }];`

Comment: @Veeram, thank you it works. Please write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query.

`$first` to keep the additional fields & `$avg` to get the average rating.

```
query = [
  { "$match": { "resturantName": resturantName} },
  { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$resturantName", 
       "resturantLocation": {"$first":"$resturantLocation"}, 
       "total_average_rating": { "$avg": "$avgRating" 
        } 
     } 
  }
];
```